# jspViewResolver and @RestController

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Learning Restful web service using Spring MVC and angularJS.

**Background story:**

I was doing some form submission particular PUT method I was getting 405 method not allowed..

[Spring MVC PUT Request returns 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719823/spring-mvc-put-request-returns-405-method-not-allowed)

One of the answers stated to should change to from @Controller to @RestController much cleaner implementation.

**Setup:**

I use jspViewResolver to direct my pages.

**app-dispatcher-servlet**

```
// -- app-dispatcher-servlet

<!-- ViewResolver JSP -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Like so

```
// -- Controller

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/spa")
public class spaController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String pagIndex(Model model){

      /* some code here */
      return "spa"; // Goes to --> spa.jsp
    }
}
```

**Problem**

But once I change `@Controller` to `@RestController`  spa.jsp page doesn't show up just String 'spa' is returned....

Right now I created two controllers which I think is redundant... looks something like this

**spaController**  -- handles all jsp pages

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/spa")
public class spaController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String pagIndex(Model model){

     /* some code */
     model.addAttribute("bookForm", new Book());

     return "spa";
  }
}
```

**spaRestController**  -- rest end point

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/spa")
public class spaRestController {

@Autowired
private BookDao bookDao;

// Get list of books
@RequestMapping(path="/booklist", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public Map<String, Object> getListBooks(){
    System.out.println("method called");

    List<Book> books = bookDao.getBookList();

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("results", books);

    return data;
 }

// Save only
@RequestMapping(path="/booklist/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String save(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody Book book, BindingResult result){

    System.out.println("Save method clicked");
    System.out.println(book);
    System.out.println(result);
    return null;
};

}
```

**Question:**

1. I think having two controllers is a bit redundant is there away to combine these two?
2. Is there a better way of handling this?

Thank you all...

Comment: Don't use `@RestController`. Just use `@Controller` and annotate the methods that need to return anything else with `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: If I use `@Controller` I get 405 method not allowed... when I use @RestController the error goes away.  Like the suggestion stated its due to csrf protection.

Comment: You want 1 controller. `@RestController` is nothing more then `@Controller` annotated with `@ResponseBody`. If you copy the methods as is, and annotate those now in the `spaRestController` with `@ResonseBody` next to `@RequestMapping` they are basically the same as before and should work. If they don't there is something else wrong.

Comment: If you need a REST webapp, why are you using webpages (jsp)?

Comment: Check my answer on your previous question regarding the endpoints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719823/spring-mvc-put-request-returns-405-method-not-allowed/41099625#41099625

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thank you ... let me trouble shoot a little bit... just odd...

Comment: @RamanujanR hummm... thought about this question for a night... you got a good point.  I am still learning so when developing a REST webapp HTML and Java can be completely separate? Right now my JSP is within WEB-INF.  I should get rid of java code within my jsp and change it to html move it outside of WEB-INF? And use Angularjs as a intermediate to data bind server and the view.... does that sound about right?

Comment: @Sohlowmawn thank you....

Comment: @EricHuang You can create a Spring REST project which has no view; means all controllers are annotated with `@RestController` and returns JSON (or a response model object). Create a separate project for client side in Angular2. Use angular http ajax calls to your REST api. After development, during production, if you need those two as a single project, you need some tricks. If you are using `angular-cli`, after development, you can build and optimize all client code to html/js by `ng build --prod` command. Then copy all html/js files in `dist` folder to Spring project's _webapp_ folder.