# Spring MVC, error code 405, method not allowed

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm getting this in the console when I'm trying to update data in my database, using spring mvc and ajax from my jsp.

```
http://localhost:8080/my_project/activerutilisateur/user 405 (Méthode Non Autorisée)
```

See my code below:

**DAO**

```
public Utilisateur updateUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(utilisateur);
    return utilisateur;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/activerutilisateur/{username}", method=RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Utilisateur activerUtilisateur(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Utilisateur utilisateur) {
    utilisateur = service.getUtilisateurById(username);
    utilisateur.setEnable(true);
    return service.updateUtilisateur(utilisateur);
}
```

**Ajax request**

```
<script>
      function activerUtilisateur(username) {

          var user = {"username" : username}

          $.ajax({
              contentType: 'application/json',
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'activerutilisateur/',
              data : JSON.stringify(user),

              error: function(xhr,error,textStatus){
                  console.log(textStatus);
              },

              complete: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log('complete done');
              },

              success: function(data) {
                  alert('success done');
              }
          });
      }   
    </script>
```

It's the only method which doesn't work in the project

Someone could please help me to find what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing the 405 in your server log? Or only in your browser console? It's possible something in front of Spring is returning that 405. Also, you might want to specify here a bit more about your environment, including Spring version, server you're running under, other web-relevant components/libraries.

Comment: No 405 in the server log but I have this in my tomcat console WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported, Spring version 4.1.5. RELEASED

Comment: It seems like maybe Spring isn't handling those URLs, then. That maybe you didn't get it fully configured, like in web.xml or with annotation scanning? Do you have an @Controller annotation on the class itself? Do you see evidence in your Tomcat log/console that Spring is indeed grabbing URLs when the application starts?

Comment: of course I have @Controller annotation on the class. You know it's the only method which doesn't work in the project

Comment: We know that now. You should add that information to the question so that people know the whole context of the situation.

Comment: Well, your latest code has "RequestMethod.PUT", while your Ajax call still has "POST", so that *should* return a 405.

Comment: I changed the ajax code on "PUT" also and the result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong here :

https://matthewbusche.com/blog2/2016/08/06/using-csrf-with-spring-security-and-ajax-calls/

It's due to csrf

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is a `POST` method, but you are reading the pathVariable, instead of any request body, normally in `POST` call you need to send Payload to your controller. And in Ajax, you are passing

`url: 'activerutilisateur/'+username` ----> for PathVariable

`data: {'username' : username}` ----> There is no requestBody in Controller for this payload.

You should update your controller to have a Request Body as an Argument.

**Edited:** I ran below code and its working fine in my local machine

JSP/JS Code:

```
<script>
      function activerUtilisateur(username) {

          var user = {
                   "username" : username
                     }
                    $.ajax({
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'activerutilisateur/',
                        data : JSON.stringify(user),
                        error: function(data){
                            console.log('Motif erreur : '+data);
                        },
                        complete: function(data) {
                            console.log('complete done');
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('success done');
                        }
                    });
      }   
    </script>
```

Controller Code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/activerutilisateur/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Utilisateur activerUtilisateur(@RequestBody Utilisateur user) {

        service.activerUtilisateur(username);
        return user;
    }
```

Model code:

```
public class Utilisateur {

    private String username ;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Also, it seems you have enabled csrf protection, so check [Sending CSRF Token from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26963573/3530898) for sending csrf token in the call to the controller.

Comment: Thanks

Not working. Is it possible that troubleshout coming from spring security?

Comment: I have updated the code and its working fine for me, can you share spring security code which you are referring to. Please add any new code in your qs post only.

Comment: Hi Amit
Can you please tell me what is qs?
Thanks

Comment: @FooBayo: It seems you have enabled csrf protection, so check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26963573/3530898 for sending csrf token in the call to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this is your Utilisateur model class :

```
public class Utilisateur {
    private String username ;
    // getter & setter

}
```

In your Controller   :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/activerutilisateur/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Utilisateur activerUtilisateur(@RequestBody Utilisateur user) {
        return service.activerUtilisateur(user.getUsername());
    }
```

In your Ajax Call :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function activerUtilisateur(username){
              var user = {
               "username" : username
                 }
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'activerutilisateur/',
                    data : JSON.stringify(user)
                    error: function(xhr, error, textStatus){
                        console.log('Motif erreur : '+textStatus);
                    },

                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }   
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks

Not working. Is it possible that troubleshout coming from spring security?

Comment: Yes ,if you have a bad spring security configuration will be get a HTTP Status 405 can you add your spring security configuration